# Convert this list, tuple in list only in Python?

Tags: python, list

I have a list like this:

```
[[(2L,)], [(3L,)]]
```

I want to convert into into the list like:

```
[2, 3]
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Is this level of nesting is known and constant?

Comment: Reading your question, the answer may well be `[lst[0][0][0], lst[1][0][0]]`. if that's not what you want, please add some details.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use list comprehensions:

If tuples contain just 1 item:

```
>>> lis = [[(2L,)], [(3L,)]]
>>> [ y[0] for x in lis for y in x]
[2L, 3L]
```

If the tuples contain more than 1 item:

```
>>> [z for x in lis for y in x for z in y]
[2L, 3L]
```

This will work for any amount of nesting:

```
from collections import Iterable
def flatten(collection):
  for element in collection:
    if isinstance(element, Iterable) and not isinstance(element, basestring):
      for x in flatten(element):
        yield x
    else:
      yield element
>>> list(flatten(lis))
[2L, 3L]
>>> lis = [[(2L,)], [(3L,(4,(5,)))]]
>>> list(flatten(lis))
[2L, 3L, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a list comprehension and convert long to int:

```
>>> L = [[(2L,)], [(3L,)]]
>>> result = [int(y[0]) for x in L for y in x]
>>> result
[2, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of the trailing L, use `int()`:

```
>>> L = [[(2L,)], [(3L,)]]
>>> [int(i[0][0]) for i in L]
[2, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> d = [[(2L,)], [(3L,)]]
>>> map(lambda x: x[0][0], d)
[2L, 3L]
```

Comment: I don't think it is a good idea to use `map` where a list comprehension will be more readable.

Comment: Equivalent list comprehension: `[x[0][0] for x in d]`.